# How could I filter array of objects with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby

I want to filter items with the same `flight_date`, `departure_at`, 'arrival_at', 'from', 'to', 'price'.

Otherwise, I will keep the lasted one (by `updated_at` field).

How could I do this with ruby

## Original array

```
[
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55c553af506f6325ef000005"),
  "flight_date": new Date("2015-08-13T08:00:00+0800"),
  "departure_at": new Date("2015-08-13T19:35:00+0800"),
  "arrival_at": new Date("2015-08-13T23:15:00+0800"),
  "from": "KHH",
  "to": "KIX",
  "updated_at": new Date(1438995375908),
  "price": 3898
},
...
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55c553af506f6325ef000009"),
  "flight_date": new Date("2015-08-13T08:00:00+0800"),
  "departure_at": new Date("2015-08-13T19:35:00+0800"),
  "arrival_at": new Date("2015-08-13T23:15:00+0800"),
  "from": "KHH",
  "to": "KIX",
  "updated_at": new Date(1438995375999),
  "price": 3898
}
]
```

## Expected output array

```
[
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("55c553af506f6325ef000005"),
      "flight_date": new Date("2015-08-13T08:00:00+0800"),
      "departure_at": new Date("2015-08-13T19:35:00+0800"),
      "arrival_at": new Date("2015-08-13T23:15:00+0800"),
      "from": "KHH",
      "to": "KIX",
      "updated_at": new Date(1438995375999),
      "price": 3898
    }
]
```

Comment: Thats not even a ruby array - never seen code like `new Date(...)` in Ruby.  Your code does not compile in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

My understand is that, given an array of hashes, you want to group the hashes `h` by the value of the array:

```
[h[:flight_date], h[:departure_at], h[:arrival_at],
  h[:from], h[:to], h[:price]]
```

and within each group you want to keep the one for which `h[:updated_at]` is largest. If that is correct, this is one way to do that, using [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
def filter_flights(arr)
  arr.group_by { |h| [h[:flight_date], h[:departure_at], h[:arrival_at],
  h[:from], h[:to], h[:price]] }.
    values.
    map { |a| a.max_by { |h| h[:updated_at] } }
end
```

Your array of hashes cannot be used as is, so I've simplified it.

```
arr = [
{
  "_id": "55c553af506f6325ef000005",
  "flight_date":  "2015-08-13T08:00:00+0800",
  "departure_at": "2015-08-13T19:35:00+0800",
  "arrival_at":   "2015-08-13T23:15:00+0800",
  "from": "KHH",
  "to": "KIX",
  "updated_at": 1438995375908,
  "price": 3898
},
{
  "_id": "55c553af506f6325ef000009",
  "flight_date": "2015-08-13T08:00:00+0800",
  "departure_at": "2015-08-13T19:35:00+0800",
  "arrival_at": "2015-08-13T23:15:00+0800",
  "from": "KHH",
  "to": "KIX",
  "updated_at": 1438995375999,
  "price": 3898
}
]

filter_flights(arr)
  #=> [{:_id=>"55c553af506f6325ef000005",
  #     :flight_date=>"2015-08-13T08:00:00+0800",
  #     :departure_at=>"2015-08-13T19:35:00+0800",
  #     :arrival_at=>"2015-08-13T23:15:00+0800",
  #     :from=>"KHH",
  #     :to=>"KIX",
  #     :updated_at=>1438995375999,
  #     :price=>3898}]
```

**Alternative**

Whenever a problem can be solved using `Enumerable#group_by`, you can be sure that there's another way (that's generally equally good) using [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`). Here it is:

```
def filter_flights(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
    a = [g[:flight_date], g[:departure_at], g[:arrival_at],
         g[:from], g[:to], g[:price]]
    h.update(a=>g) { |_,o,n| (o[:updated_at] >= n[:updated_at]) ? o : n }
 end.values
```

Here I've used the form of `Hash#update` that uses a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged (the two hashes being the values of the block variables `o` and `n`).